# Auto require array of dependancies into object

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is there anyway to automate this, really redundant.

```
define("simba", ['meta',"slider", "quickview", "share", "mylife"], function(meta, slider, quickview, share, mylife){
    var simba = {
        meta: meta,
        slider: slider,
        quickview: quickview,
        share: share,
        mylife: mylife
    };
    return simba
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, but you could create an `autoDefine` function that will generate a new function wich then generates the desired object.

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zLfGkxj21S7B2SaQmMhO?p=preview

The first approach uses `new Function` to avoid creating a closure over the `autoDefine` function scope, to make sure that the `name` and `dependencies` variables gets garbage collected. However, this method is slower since it has to do some string manipulations.

```
autoDefine("simba", ['meta',"slider", "quickview", "share", "mylife"]);

function autoDefine(name, dependencies) {
    var json = dependencies.join(',').replace(/([^,]+),?/g, '"$1":$1,').replace(/,$/, '');
    define(name, dependencies, new Function(dependencies, 'return eval("({"+\'' + json + '\'+"})");'));
}
```

Here's another approach that takes advantage of closures, however if **RequireJS** doesn't free the factory function once executed, the dependencies array will stay in memory.

```
function autoDefine2(name, dependencies) {
    define(name, dependencies, function () {
        var i = 0,
            len = arguments.length,
            o = {};

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            o[dependencies[i]] = arguments[i];
        }

        return o;
    });
}
```

Here are [**performance tests**](http://jsperf.com/auto-define-perfs) that shows that `autoDefine2` performs way better than `autoDefine`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what the performance differences of retaining the dependency array vs having it encoded in a Function body are. Would be different between JS runtimes I suppose. Either way, there is nothing stopping the AMD framework from deleting the factory function once the module has been realised I suppose. This would also free the closed-over array.

Comment: Sadly, both these solutions wouldn't compile @paulgrime's did. Not sure why. You're solutions came up with the error `ENOENT, no such file or directory` trying to find `simba.js`.

Comment: I think if the module name is passed as the first parameter to `define` then the second needs to be thd dependency array.

Comment: @PaulGrime, Yeah, if RequireJS frees the function, it would allow everything to get garbage collected, I added a note in my answer and also added a performance test if you are interested. However, the results are what to be expected, the second method is way faster than the first.

Comment: this is still not working and I've tried [tinkering](https://gist.github.com/reggi/5465234) with `.apply` and it still breaks.

Comment: @ThomasReggi, I added a link to a working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLfGkxj21S7B2SaQmMhO?p=preview) (make sure your console is opened). It seems to work very well. Could you give me more details about the issues you are experiencing?

Comment: @plalx Sorry for coming back to this almost a months later but I still cant get it to compile. I think it works fine but I can't get the complier to realize whats going on. Here's my main.js and my terminal error: https://gist.github.com/reggi/5629908

Answer (score 1):

This maybe?

```
(function (deps) {
define("simba", deps, function () {
    var simba = {};
    for (var i = deps.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        simba[deps[i]] = arguments[i];
    }
    return simba;
});
}(['meta', "slider", "quickview", "share", "mylife"]));
```

Would maybe defeat the RequireJS optimiser though, so not sure of the benefits.

Comment: This compiles but it gives me a console error it appears that meta, slider, quickview etc are not being imported and it's looking for them in the local project (wrong directories).